# gulp serve will return this error "File does not exist: C:\src\webparts\helloWorld\HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharepoint, gulp, yo

When i run the following command:-

```
C:\helloworld-webpart>gulp serve
```

i will get this error :-

```
[21:22:19] Error - 'configure-webpack' sub task errored after 289 ms
 File does not exist: C:\src\webparts\helloWorld\HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json
File does not exist: C:\src\webparts\helloWorld\HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\src\webparts\helloWorld\HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json'
```

[image]

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the file `HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json`?

Comment: @EthanSnow no it is not there... can you advice?

Comment: @EthanSnow how i can generate this file?

Answer (score 0):

Check the casing of the file paths.  Note the casing used in config.json vs the casing actually used in file system.  May not be an issue on a Windows machine, but perhaps the automated build is using a different OS where this is an issue?

For example, in your specific example, the path referenced is:
\helloWorld\HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json

Perhaps it's actually:
\HelloWorld\HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you try to following SPFx Microsoft tutorial, and, for some reason, this file not generated. I generate a SPFx in VSCode with same name, and will copy the file-text structure for you generate this, like bellow:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx/client-side-web-part-manifest.schema.json",
  "id": "d0074c68-ef7e-4aba-9021-12b57f84aa4d",
  "alias": "HelloWorldWebPart",
  "componentType": "WebPart",

  // The "*" signifies that the version should be taken from the package.json
  "version": "*",
  "manifestVersion": 2,

  // If true, the component can only be installed on sites where Custom Script is allowed.
  // Components that allow authors to embed arbitrary script code should set this to true.
  // https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f
  "requiresCustomScript": false,
  "supportedHosts": ["SharePointWebPart"],

  "preconfiguredEntries": [{
    "groupId": "5c03119e-3074-46fd-976b-c60198311f70", // Other
    "group": { "default": "Other" },
    "title": { "default": "HelloWorld" },
    "description": { "default": "HelloWorld description" },
    "officeFabricIconFontName": "Page",
    "properties": {
      "description": "HelloWorld"
    }
  }]
}
```

Please, give us the feedback if it's works.